# ffmpeg combine a video and the srt with multiple lines?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I know how to combine a video 1.mp4 and a srt 1.srt document by ffmpeg,
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 1.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -crf 23 video-with-subtitles.mkv
but here I want to add the subtitles on the right hand side of my screen with multi-line on the RHS scrolling up as the time goes. Is there some command in ffmpeg to do it?
Allow the video picture and the subtitle coincide here.
I need to find one parameter to control the position of the subtitles and
also one parameter to control the number of multi-lines.

Answer (score 1):

[edit note]
I didn't do a very good research in the original post. Hopefully, I got here is a little better.
[/edit note]

1. FFmpeg has a very little control (if any) over the behavior of subtitle streams UNLESS you want to draw subtitles directly on video frames (`drawtext` filter).
2. [SRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) supposedly can specify the subtitle position [see this post](https://superuser.com/q/642265/1669011)
3. There are many other subtitle formats out there: ASS/SSA, WebVTT, etc. ASS apparently supports scrolling [link](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-82025.html). WebVTT supposedly supports scrolling via [regions](https://www.w3.org/TR/webvtt1/#regions) but it appears not implemented yet.
4. Showing multiple lines in SRT. [Here is a link](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/391480-SRT-blank-line-character) discussing a trick to do so (I apparently jumped the gun with the initial `<br>` suggestion)
5. There are a lot of resources out there on subtitle authoring, including free tools. So do your own research

Comment: I learn some new knowledge from here, could you add some details for this operation?